# Simulating data using existing data and probability

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, distribution, bayesian

I have measured multiple attributes (height, species, crown width, condition etc) for about 1500 trees in a city.  Using remote sensing techniques I also have the heights for the rest of the 9000 trees in the city.  I want to simulate/generate/estimate the missing attributes for these unmeasured trees by using their heights.

From the measured data I can obtain proportion of each species in the measured population (and thus a rough probability), height distributions for each species, height-crown width relationships for the species, species-condition relationship and so on.  I want to use the height data for the unmeasured trees to first estimate the species and then estimate the rest of the attributes too using probability theory.  So for a height of say 25m its more likely to be a Cedar (height range 5 - 30 m) rather than a Mulberry tree (height range 2 -8 m) and more likely to be a cedar (50% of population) than an oak (same height range but 2% of population) and hence will have a crown width of 10m and have a health condition of 95% (based on the distributions for cedar trees in my measured data).  But also I am expecting some of the other trees of 25m to be given oak, just less frequently than cedar based on the proportion in population.

Is there a way to do this using probability theory in R preferably utilising Bayesian or machine learning methods?

Im not asking for someone to write the code for me - I am fairly experienced with R.  I just want to be pointed in the right direction i.e. a package that does this kind of thing neatly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you want to predict a categorical variable, i.e. the species, you should consider using a tree regression, a method which can be found in the R packages rpart and RandomForest. These models excel when you have a discrete number of categories and you need to slot your observations into those categories. I think those packages would work in your application. As a comparison, you can also look at multinomial regression (mnlogit, nnet, maxent) which can also predict categorical outcomes; unfortunately multinomial regression can get unwieldy with large numbers of outcomes and/or large datasets.

If you want to then predict the individual values for individual trees in your species, first run a regression of all of your measured variables, including species type, on the measured trees. Then take the categorical labels that you predicted and predict out-of-sample for the unmeasured trees where you use the categorical labels as predictors for the unmeasured variable of interest, say tree height. That way the regression will predict the average height for that species/dummy variable, plus some error and incorporating any other information you have on that out-of-sample tree.

If you want to use a Bayesian method, you consider using a hierarchical regression to model these out-of-sample predictions. Sometimes hierarchical models do better at predicting as they tend to be fairly conservative. Consider looking at the package Rstanarm for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you looking over Bayesian Networks with table CPDs over your random variables. This is a generative model that can handle missing data and do inference over casual relationships between variables. Bayesian Network structure can be specified by-hand or learned from data by a algorithm.

R has several implementations of Bayesian Networks with bnlearn being one of them: http://www.bnlearn.com/

Please see a tutorial on how to use it here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/bayesian-network-in-r-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

For each species, the distribution of the other variables (height, width, condition) is probably a fairly simple bump. You can probably model the height and width as a joint Gaussian distribution; dunno about condition. Anyway with a joint distribution for variables other than species, you can construct a mixture distribution of all those per-species bumps, with mixing weights equal to the proportion of each species in the available data. Given the height, you can find the conditional distribution of the other variables conditional on height (and it will also be a mixture distribution). Given the conditional mixture, you can sample from it as usual: pick a bump with frequency equal to its mixing weight, and then sample from the selected bump.

Sounds like a good problem. Good luck and have fun.